# Converting number to currency in MERN app - where to include the function to generate the currency output?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, currency-formatting

I am trying to generate a number to display as currency.  I am using the following code in the app.js file:

```
function currencyFormat(num) {
        return '$' + num.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,')
      };
```

In the ejs file to intake the data I have:

```
<input id="input" class="form-control" type="number" name="targetVolume">
```

In the show file to display the data, I have:

```
<p><span>Volume: </span><%= plan.targetVolume %></p>
```

Where do I put the **currencyFormat** to display the inputted number to display it as currency on the show page?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use Javascript's [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) class for this purpose to implement your function.  Like so:

```
function currencyFormat(num) {
  const currency = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { 
                                                    style: 'currency',
                                                    currency: 'USD'
                                                  })
  return currency.format(number)
};
```

It's tested; it's documented; it's adaptable to different locales and currencies.

Then call your function when rendering the currency value, something like this.

```
<p><span>Price: </span><%= currencyFormat(plan.price) %></p>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that.  When I console.log the function with a number in it, I do get the currency.  But when I put it in the ejs show file as:                          <p><span>Volume: </span><%= currencyFormat(plan.targetVolume) %></p>

it shows currencyFormat is not defined.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { style: 'currency',currency: 'TRY'}).format(plan.price).slice(4) %>
```

I used this code :)